# How to fix an 'Optional nil' on a RevealViewController() Gesture Recognizer?

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a tap and pan gesture recognizer to my `RevealViewController()` and I'm getting a `Value of optional type 'UIGestureRecognizer?' must be unwrapped`. How should I unwrap this?

// My App

[image]
[image]

// Main.storyboard

[image]

// HomeVC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    if self.revealViewController() != nil{
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController()!.tapGestureRecognizer())
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController()!.panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `revealViewController()` declared?

Comment: I'm using the ```sw_rear``` and ```sw_front``` in my ```Main.storyboard```, then I'm using my ```menuBtn``` to open the ```revealViewController()```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Please edit your question and add the function `revealViewController()`.

Comment: I'm not using any function for ```revealViewController()```. The ```menuBtn``` controls it.

Comment: The button target is not referencing the view controller as you think, it is creating a new instance of it.

Comment: So do I need to do a ```revealViewController()``` function?

Comment: The easy solution is `self.revealViewController()!` but this could cause the next question *why is my code crashing?* Without knowing where this optional  `revealViewController()` is coming from the question cannot be answered reliably. And if each call of `revealViewController()` creates a new instance the code won't work anyway.

Comment: I agree with @vadian. I can provide a possible solution below but I'm not sure what ```revealViewController()``` is, what it does and why it's an optional

Comment: Every time you say `self.revealViewController()` you are calling a function but you are not showing us what it is. If this is the name of an actual view controller, then you are just making throw-away view controllers over and over again, which is pointless, as vadian has rightly said.

Comment: I don't have a function, I don't know what to do for the tap and pan gesture recognizers

Comment: The ```revealViewController()``` is what lets the ```SWRevealViewController()``` open and close

Answer (score 0):

This question is vague and you didn't provide a lot of context so excuse the answer if it's not exactly what you need but why not do a simple `if let` statement to gracefully unwrap it.

```
if let gestureTap = self.revealViewController()?.tapGestureRecognizer(){
     if let gesturePan = self.revealViewController()?.panGestureRecognizer(){

self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureTap)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesturePan)
     }
}
```

Comment: I added images and the code you provided, but the tap and pan isn't working. However it's not showing the 'Optional nil' anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I got the tap and pan gesture recognizers by adding:

```
menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.panGestureRecognizer), for: .touchUpInside)

menuBtn.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer), for: .touchUpInside)
```